# A motivating argument for studying determinants of $2\times 2$ matrices with prime entries in relation to Goldbach's conjecture.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, determinant, simplicial-stuff, goldbachs-conjecture

Let $\Bbb{P}$ be the set of *odd* primes.  Let $X_n$ for $n \geq 3$ be the Goldbach solution set $X_n = \{(p,q) \in \Bbb{P}\times \Bbb{P} : 2n = p + q \}$.

Suppose that for combinatorial reasons we are concerned with the size of the solution set, since for example it's not always $1$: $13 + 3 = 11 + 5 = 16$.

**Question 1.** Does $n = 6$ appear to be the largest integer such that $|X_n| = 1$, namely $5 + 7 = 12$ (and that's all)?

Now consider the case of $2n = 16$.  We have that $\det \begin{pmatrix} 13 & 3 \\ 11 & 5 \end{pmatrix} = 2 \cdot 16$ and this seems to happen all time, i.e. whenever there are at least two solutions $(p,q), (r,s) \in X_n$ then their determinant is a multiple of $2n$.

**Question 2.**  Can you think of a reason why this might be the case?

Define the **standard form of the matrix** for two distinct solutions $(a,b), (c,d)$ where $a \lt c \lt d \lt b$ to be
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b  \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
$$

Intuitively speaking, this gives the least, positive multiple of $2n$ as a result.

---

Next, what is the relationship between all the solutions?  Can we have an equation in $2 \times 2$ determinants?

I think this also is true.  Take for example the case of $|X_{23}| = 4$ i.e. $X_{23} = \{ (23,23), (41,5), (43,3), (29, 17)\}$

Then there are a total of 6 relationships (matrices) by looking at a square graph and filling in the two diagonal relationships as well.

They are, in standard form:

$$
\det \begin{pmatrix} 43 & 3 \\ 23 & 23 \end{pmatrix} = 20 \cdot 46 \\
\det \begin{pmatrix} 43 & 3 \\ 41 & 5 \end{pmatrix} = 2 \cdot 46 \\
\det \begin{pmatrix} 43 & 3 \\ 29 & 17 \end{pmatrix} = 14 \cdot 46 \\
\det \begin{pmatrix} 41 & 5 \\ 23 & 23 \end{pmatrix} = 18 \cdot 46 \\
\det \begin{pmatrix} 41 & 5 \\ 29 & 17 \end{pmatrix} = 12 \cdot 46 \\
\det \begin{pmatrix} 29 & 17 \\ 23 & 23 \end{pmatrix} = 6 \cdot 46 
$$

Now see that if we split their values up in a certain way (we can just look at the mulitple scalar), we have:

$18 + 12 + 6 = 2 + 14 + 20$

And of course you can move all to one side to get an alternating-sign summation that equals zero.  But how should we assign the coefficient $\pm 1$?  I did some brain storming.  And we should do it like so:

Assign a letter $A, B, C, D$ to each solution, simply do it in the order given i.e: $X_{23} = \{A:(23,23), B:(41,5), C:(43,3), D:(29, 17)\}$.

Then draw a square with labels $A,B,C,D$ at the vertices:

```
A---- B
|     | 
|     |
C-----D
```

Now, the matrices have an orientation, e.g. $\begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \end{pmatrix}$ will correspond to an edge direciton of $A \to B$, so fill in the square along with diagonals and edge directions according to the $6$ oriented matrices presented above in the vertical list of determinants.  You get a picture that looks like this:

[image: Goldbach's conjecture simplex orientation]

Notice that the $+1$ sign lies on a "commuting triangle"-looking face, and the $-1$ sign applies only to the *odd man out* vertex $C$ which points to all other vertices. $C$ is the only vertex that points to all other vertices, in other words and its outgoing edges (relationships) get the opposite sign.

Putting this all together we get:

$$
(B \to A) + (B \to D) + (D \to A) - (C \to A) - (C \to B) - (C\to D) = 0\\
18 + 12 + 6  - 20 - 2 - 14 = 0
$$

**Question 3.** What area of mathematics does the orientation assignment most closely resemble, is it simplicial complexes or can we get even more specific? I would like to read up on whatever you specify.

**Question 4.** Can you immediately see any counter-example that would rule out the above ideas?

**Question 5.** If not 4., is there immediately an obvious proof of the above things? Namely that the determinant of a relationship is always a multiple of $2n$ and that the alternating sum of all possible relationship determinants in standard form sums to $0$?

---

Not only do we have the alternating sum of the tetrahedron, but each of its faces can also be assigned an $\pm 1$ sign and independently sum to zero, for example $14 + 6 - 20 = 0$.  I'm still unsure how this (completely separate and different) assignment relates to the larger assignment in the tetrahedron.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Question $2)$:
Writing your matrix as $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    r & s  \\
    p & q  
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

With $r+s=2n=p+q$

Add the first column to the second.  Noting that $p+q=2n=r+s$ we see that your determinant is the same as the determinant of $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    r & 2n  \\
    p & 2n  
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

which is obviously divisible by $2n$.

Comment: I see, you used an elementary row op and that preserves the determinant?

Comment: Also, I think you meant add the columns!

Comment: Invariance under elementary row operations is one of the key properties of determinants.  For $2\times 2$ matrices, of course, one could just write it out.  And, yes...for whatever reason I took the transpose of your matrix (which also doesn't change the determinant).  I can edit to fix that, if it matters.

Comment: no, your post is fine.  Thank  you!  What about the other questions such as assigning orientation.  How should we accomplish that in general?  I am a simplicially new person.

Comment: I already edited it.  I don't have time to look at the other questions now, I'll try to return to them later.

Answer (score 2):

Question 2. The vector $(1,1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $2n$. The sum of eigenvalues is  the trace. So the second eigenvalue $b$ is an integer. Hence the matrix is aimilar to $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2n & a \\
0 & b \end{array}\right)$$ Hence the determinant of the matrix is $2nb$, a multiple of $2n$.